# Camera2 api error failed to create capture session

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am trying to implement the Camera2 api in my android application. When I click the take picture button, the image gets freezes in the preview and error message comes as "Failed to create capture session; configuration failed". The application has minimum api as 21 and I have set the permissions as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
```

The code in MainActivity.java is as follows:

```
package com.example.dioglgt.cameratest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Button button;
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidCameraApi";
    private Button takePictureButton;
    private TextureView textureView;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }
    private String cameraId;
    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest captureRequest;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private File file;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_page);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        takePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_takepicture);
        assert takePictureButton != null;
        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

            openCamera();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
    final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            createCameraPreview();
        }
    };
    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }
    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void takePicture() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 240;
            int height = 180;
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pic.jpg");
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream output = null;
                    try {
                        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        output.write(bytes);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != output) {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    Log.e(TAG, "so far good");
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }
    protected void updatePreview() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void closeCamera() {
        if (null != cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != imageReader) {
            imageReader.close();
            imageReader = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        //closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }


}
```

I am testing the application in a device having Nougat.Please guide in solving this issue. I am putting the logcat below:

```
10-30 07:44:27.218 3060-3061/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]
10-30 07:44:27.482 3067-5669/? E/mm-camera: <ISP   ><ERROR> 1050: isp_handler_control_streamoff: stream_off 2 2 ide 20003
10-30 07:44:27.482 3067-5669/? E/mm-camera: <ISP   ><ERROR> 1050: isp_handler_control_streamoff: stream_off 2 2 ide 20003

                                            [ 10-30 07:44:27.488 28733: 5783 D/         ]
                                            cmdtype=MM_CAMERA_CMD_TYPE_EXIT

                                            [ 10-30 07:44:27.528 28733: 5778 D/         ]
                                            cmdtype=MM_CAMERA_CMD_TYPE_EXIT

                                            [ 10-30 07:44:27.530 28733: 5777 D/         ]
                                            cmdtype=MM_CAMERA_CMD_TYPE_EXIT
10-30 07:44:27.547 642-656/? E/Sensors: sns_reg_la.c(194):reg write: offset 1792, num bytes: 24
10-30 07:44:27.552 28733-28808/? E/QCamera3HWI: int qcamera::QCamera3HardwareInterface::configureStreamsPerfLocked(camera3_stream_configuration_t *): Blob size greater than 4k and multiple streams are on encoder output
10-30 07:44:27.552 28733-28808/? E/Camera3-Device: Camera 0: configureStreamsLocked: Set of requested inputs/outputs not supported by HAL
10-30 07:44:27.552 28733-28808/? E/CameraDeviceClient: endConfigure: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
10-30 07:44:27.558 4234-4234/com.example.dioglgt.cameratest E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 3: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
10-30 07:44:29.830 4810-4838/? E/radish: radish_send_nd_packet sent 72 bytes
```

Comment: ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR may not support on all devices, may be you first try to use ImageFormat.JPEG as all device support.

Comment: ImageFormat.JPEG did not work. So, i tried with ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR. But nothing seems to work. Can someone show me a working example?

Comment: I try almost some of your project code inside our previous camera app, it OK no error. Instead, i use a global variance storage the captureRequest =capturebuilder.build(). and call it at           camerasession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest,capturecallback,null);

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. It always fails at capturesession.

Comment: Your current sample code is querying sizes for JPEG, but then creating an ImageReader with format RAW.  You need to make sure you query for RAW sizes if you're going to use that; they aren't usually the same (JPEG is often cropped a little bit, comparatively).

You also don't store the image reader anywhere, so it might be getting GC'd before the session is created.  The Surface you pass to the camera is equivalent to a weak pointer; put your reader in a member field or equivalent.

It'd help to see actual full system logcat; it has more information about why the session creation failed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the system logcat.

Comment: The error from the camera HAL suggests you have an unsupported combination of outputs.  It looks like you're just grabbing the first size from the list for both the texture view and the JPEG; that may leave you with too-high of a resolution pair, depending on your device's supported hardware level.  If you drop your preview resolution to <=1080p, does that work?

Comment: Dropping the preview resolution worked. But I am hard coding it,           
texture.setDefaultBufferSize(600, 800);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(moved from comments as an answer):

The error from the camera HAL suggests you have an unsupported combination of outputs. It looks like you're just grabbing the first size from the list for both the texture view and the JPEG; that may leave you with too-high of a resolution pair, depending on your device's supported hardware level. If you drop your preview resolution to <=1080p, does that work?

In response to hardcoding the buffer size to 800,600:

It's unlikely that 600,800 is an actual supported preview resolution; you should iterate over to list to find a size that meets your criteria (such as the biggest resolution <= 1080p, etc).  Unless you're on a relatively unusual android device, the camera resolutions will all be landscape-oriented - (800, 600) instead of (600, 800).  The camera API will round the resolution you give it to a supported size, for Surface/TextureView, but that may not result in a matching aspect ratio in all cases, so it's a bit risky to not select a supported size explicitly.

Comment: Thanks brother. This actually helped.

Comment: could you show me how to hard-code the buffer size? i'm currently experiencing the same problem here

Answer (score 6):

You should remove "ImageFormat.JPEG" support, e.g. remove below line if you are using:

```
    ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
```

And instead use RAW-SENSOR:

```
  ImageReader mRawImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(rawWidth, rawHeight, ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR, 1);
```

Or If you still want the jpeg format instead of raw put constants in the line

```
  ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.JPEG,1);
```

if you want a continued streaming even after the error
call

```
 CameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surface, callback{
     @Override
     public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session){
     //call the function that creates the preview
     }
 }, handler);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same issue recently, after long time investigating, I found that both the preview size and output size set to high resolution (I doubt it's the system preventing too much memory usage). after I set the preview resolution to smaller size (by calling

```
previewTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(smallerPreviewSize.getWidth(), smallerPreviewSize.getHeight())
```

in setup preview function, it worked for me, hopefully this answer helps.

By the way, here is the code that I used to choose the proper preview size:

```
Size smallerPreviewSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class));
protected Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
    List<Size> smallEnough = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Size size : choices) {
        if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 4 / 3 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
            smallEnough.add(size);
        }
    }
    if (smallEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.max(smallEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
    }

    return choices[choices.length - 1];
}
public class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
@Override
public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
    return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
            (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
}

}
```