# Android Camera2 displays black and distorted JPEG image on TextureView?

Tags: android, android-camera2, textureview

Im making a test app for a friend, on the Samsung S20.

The Samsung S20 has a ToF (Time of Flight) camera facing the back.

I will like to display the ToF image preview & regular camera preview on a `TextureView` side by side.

Im able to get the ToF sensor and convert its raw output to visual output using a color mask and display depth ranges visually (red farthest, oranges, etc..), see the screenshot:

[image]

**Below is relevant code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="619dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF">
            <TextureView
                android:id="@+id/regularBackCamera"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.899" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Raw ToF Data"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rawData"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rawData"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rawData" />
            <TextureView
                android:id="@+id/rawData"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/regularBackCamera"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.485" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
                android:text="Back Camera"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/regularBackCamera"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regularBackCamera" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity class:**

```
/*  This is an example of getting and processing ToF data
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DepthFrameVisualizer, RegularCameraFrameVisualizer {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final int CAM_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 0;

    private TextureView rawDataView;
    private TextureView regularImageView;
    private Matrix ToFBitmapTransform;
    private Matrix regularBackCameraBitmapTransform;
    private BackToFCamera backToFCamera;
    private RegularBackCamera regularBackCamera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rawDataView = findViewById(R.id.rawData);
        regularImageView = findViewById(R.id.regularBackCamera);
        checkCamPermissions();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if ( backToFCamera !=null)
        {
            backToFCamera.getCamera().close();
            backToFCamera = null;

        }
        if ( regularBackCamera!= null)
        {
            regularBackCamera.getCamera().close();
            regularBackCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        backToFCamera = new BackToFCamera(this, this);
        String tofCameraId = backToFCamera.openCam(null);

        regularBackCamera = new RegularBackCamera(this, this);
        //pass in tofCameraId to avoid opening again since both regular cam & ToF camera are back facing
        regularBackCamera.openCam(tofCameraId);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();               // Add this line
    }

    private void checkCamPermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAM_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRawDataAvailable(Bitmap bitmap) {
        renderBitmapForToFToTextureView(bitmap, rawDataView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegularImageAvailable(Bitmap bitmap) {
        renderBitmapToTextureView( bitmap,regularImageView);
    }

    /* We don't want a direct camera preview since we want to get the frames of data directly
        from the camera and process.

        This takes a converted bitmap and renders it onto the surface, with a basic rotation
        applied.
     */
    private void renderBitmapForToFToTextureView(Bitmap bitmap, TextureView textureView) {

        if (bitmap!=null && textureView!=null) {
            Canvas canvas = textureView.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, ToFBitmapTransform(textureView), null);
            textureView.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void renderBitmapToTextureView(Bitmap bitmap, TextureView textureView) {
        if (bitmap!=null && textureView!=null)
        {
        Canvas canvas = textureView.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas!=null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, regularBackCamBitmapTransform(textureView), null);
            textureView.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        }
    }

    private Matrix ToFBitmapTransform(TextureView view) {

        if (view!=null) {
            if (ToFBitmapTransform == null || view.getWidth() == 0 || view.getHeight() == 0) {
                int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                int centerX = view.getWidth() / 2;
                int centerY = view.getHeight() / 2;

                int bufferWidth = DepthFrameAvailableListener.SAMSUNG_S20_TOF_WIDTH;
                int bufferHeight = DepthFrameAvailableListener.SAMSUNG_S20_TOF_HEIGHT;

                RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);
                RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
                matrix.setRectToRect(bufferRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

                Log.i(TAG, " rotation:" + rotation);
                if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation) {

                    matrix.postRotate(270, centerX, centerY);
                } else if (Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {

                    matrix.postRotate(90, centerX, centerY);
                } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {

                    matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
                } else {
                    //strange but works!
                    matrix.postRotate(90, centerX, centerY);
                }


                ToFBitmapTransform = matrix;
            }
        }
        return  ToFBitmapTransform;
    }

    private Matrix regularBackCamBitmapTransform(TextureView view) {
        if (view!=null) {
            if (regularBackCameraBitmapTransform == null || view.getWidth() == 0 || view.getHeight() == 0) {

                int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH,MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT);
                RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
                matrix.setRectToRect(bufferRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
                float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
                float centerY = viewRect.centerY();

                Log.i(TAG, " rotation:" + rotation);
                if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation) {

                    matrix.postRotate(270, centerX, centerY);
                } else if (Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {

                    matrix.postRotate(90, centerX, centerY);
                } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {

                    matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
                } else {
                    //strange but works!
                    matrix.postRotate(90, centerX, centerY);
                }

                regularBackCameraBitmapTransform = matrix;
            }
        }
        return regularBackCameraBitmapTransform;
    }
}
```

Listener that signals a frame is available for display, look at the function `publishOriginalBitmap()`:

```
import static com.example.opaltechaitestdepthmap.RegularBackCamera.MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
import static com.example.opaltechaitestdepthmap.RegularBackCamera.MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;

public class BackCameraFrameAvailableListener implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
    private static final String TAG = BackCameraFrameAvailableListener.class.getSimpleName();
    private RegularCameraFrameVisualizer regularCameraFrameVisualizer;

    public BackCameraFrameAvailableListener(RegularCameraFrameVisualizer regularCameraFrameVisualizer) {
        this.regularCameraFrameVisualizer = regularCameraFrameVisualizer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        try {
            Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();
          if (image != null && image.getFormat() == ImageFormat.JPEG)
            {

                publishOriginalBitmap(image);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to acquireNextImage: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void publishOriginalBitmap(final Image image) {

        if (regularCameraFrameVisualizer != null) {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    Bitmap bitmap = returnBitmap(image);
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        regularCameraFrameVisualizer.onRegularImageAvailable(bitmap);
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }

    }

    private Bitmap returnBitmap(Image image) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        // width=1920,height=1080
        int width =1920;
        int height =1080;
        if (image!=null) {

            Log.i(TAG,"returnBitmap,CONSTANT MAX width:"+MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH +",MAX height:"+MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT);
            Log.i(TAG,"BEFORE returnBitmap,image.width:"+width +",height:"+height );
            if (image!=null) {
                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                if (planes!=null && planes.length>0) {

                    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    image.close();
                    Log.i(TAG,"buffer size:"+buffer.capacity());

                        float currenBufferSize = buffer.capacity();
                        float jpegReportedArea = width * height;
                        if (currenBufferSize >=jpegReportedArea ) {
                            Log.i(TAG,"currenBufferSize >=jpegReportedArea ");

                            float quotient =  jpegReportedArea/currenBufferSize ;
                            float f_width = width * quotient;
                            width = (int) Math.ceil(f_width);
                            float f_height = height * quotient;
                            height = (int) Math.ceil(f_height);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.i(TAG,"currenBufferSize <jpegReportedArea ");
                            float quotient = currenBufferSize / jpegReportedArea;
                            float f_width = (width * quotient);
                            width = (int) Math.ceil(f_width);
                            float f_height = (height * quotient);
                            height = (int) Math.ceil(f_height);

                        }


                        Log.i(TAG,"AFTER width:"+width+",height:"+height);
                        //***here bitmap is black
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

                        buffer.rewind();
                        if (bitmap!=null) {
                            bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
                        }

                }

            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

**The interface used by the listener to signal image is ready:**

```
package com.example.opaltechaitestdepthmap;

        import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public interface RegularCameraFrameVisualizer {
    void onRegularImageAvailable(Bitmap bitmap);
```

}

**Handles camera states:**

```
public class RegularBackCamera extends CameraDevice.StateCallback {

    private static final String TAG = RegularBackCamera.class.getSimpleName();
    private static int FPS_MIN = 15;
    private static int FPS_MAX = 30;
    public static final int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920;
    public static final int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;
    private Context context;
    private CameraManager cameraManager;
    private ImageReader RawSensorPreviewReader;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder previewBuilder;
    private BackCameraFrameAvailableListener imageAvailableListener;
    private String cameraId;
    private CameraDevice camera;

    public RegularBackCamera(Context context, RegularCameraFrameVisualizer frameVisualizer) {
        this.context = context;
        cameraManager = (CameraManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        imageAvailableListener = new BackCameraFrameAvailableListener(frameVisualizer);

    }

    // Open the back camera and start sending frames
    public String openCam(String idToExclude) {
        this.cameraId  = getBackCameraID(idToExclude);
        Size size = openCamera(this.cameraId);

        //Tried this DID NOT WORK Size smallerPreviewSize =chooseSmallerPreviewSize();

                RawSensorPreviewReader = ImageReader.newInstance(MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH,
                        MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT, ImageFormat.JPEG,2);
        Log.i(TAG,"ImageFormat.JPEG, width:"+size.getWidth()+", height:"+ size.getHeight());
        RawSensorPreviewReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageAvailableListener, null);

        return this.cameraId;
    }

    private String getBackCameraID(String idToExclude) {
        String cameraId = null;
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {

            if (idToExclude!=null) {
                for (String camera : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                    //avoid getting same camera
                    if (!camera.equalsIgnoreCase(idToExclude)) {
                        //avoid return same camera twice as 1 sensor can only be accessed once
                        CameraCharacteristics chars = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(camera);
                        final int[] capabilities = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES);
                        boolean facingBack = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_BACK;

                        if (facingBack) {
                            cameraId = camera;
                            // Note that the sensor size is much larger than the available capture size
                            SizeF sensorSize = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Sensor size: " + sensorSize);

                            // Since sensor size doesn't actually match capture size and because it is
                            // reporting an extremely wide aspect ratio, this FoV is bogus
                            float[] focalLengths = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS);
                            if (focalLengths.length > 0) {
                                float focalLength = focalLengths[0];
                                double fov = 2 * Math.atan(sensorSize.getWidth() / (2 * focalLength));
                                Log.i(TAG, "Calculated FoV: " + fov);
                            }

                        }

                    }//end avoid getting same camera


                }//end for
            }
            else
            {
                for (String camera : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {

                    //avoid return same camera twice as 1 sensor can only be accessed once
                    CameraCharacteristics chars = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(camera);
                    final int[] capabilities = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES);
                    boolean facingFront = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_BACK;

                    if (facingFront) {
                        cameraId = camera;
                        // Note that the sensor size is much larger than the available capture size
                        SizeF sensorSize = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Sensor size: " + sensorSize);

                        // Since sensor size doesn't actually match capture size and because it is
                        // reporting an extremely wide aspect ratio, this FoV is bogus
                        float[] focalLengths = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS);
                        if (focalLengths.length > 0) {
                            float focalLength = focalLengths[0];
                            double fov = 2 * Math.atan(sensorSize.getWidth() / (2 * focalLength));
                            Log.i(TAG, "Calculated FoV: " + fov);
                        }

                    }
                }//end for
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return    cameraId ;
    }

    //opens camera based on ID & returns optimal size caped at maximum size based on docs
    private Size openCamera(String cameraId) {
        Size size = null;
        try{
            int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == permission) {
                if ( cameraManager!=null) {
                    if (cameraId!=null) {
                        cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, this, null);


                            CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                                    =  cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);


                            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

                        size = Collections.max(
                                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                                    new CompareSizeByArea());
                        if (size.getWidth() > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH ||  size.getHeight() > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT)
                        {
                            size = new Size( MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH ,MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT);

                        }

                       List<Size> sizes =  Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG));
                       for (int i=0; i<sizes.size(); i++)
                       {
                           Log.i(RegularBackCamera.class.toString(),"JPEG sizes, width="+sizes.get(i).getWidth()+","+"height="+sizes.get(i).getHeight());
                       }

                    }

                }
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG,"Permission not available to open camera");
            }
        }catch (CameraAccessException | IllegalStateException | SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"Opening Camera has an Exception " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  size;
    }


    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        try {
            this.camera = camera;
            previewBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Range<Integer> fpsRange = new Range<>(FPS_MIN, FPS_MAX);
            previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, fpsRange);
            previewBuilder.addTarget(RawSensorPreviewReader.getSurface());

            List<Surface> targetSurfaces = Arrays.asList(RawSensorPreviewReader.getSurface());

            camera.createCaptureSession(targetSurfaces,
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            onCaptureSessionConfigured(session);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"!!! Creating Capture Session failed due to internal error ");
                        }
                    }, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void onCaptureSessionConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Capture Session created");
        previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            session.setRepeatingRequest(previewBuilder.build(), null, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {

        if (camera!=null)
        {
            camera.close();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        if (camera!=null)
        {
            camera.close();
            Log.e(TAG,"onError,cameraID:"+camera.getId()+",error:"+error);
            camera = null;


        }
    }

    protected Size chooseSmallerPreviewSize()
    {
        CameraManager cm = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        CameraCharacteristics cc = null;
        try {
            cc = cm.getCameraCharacteristics(this.cameraId);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigs = cc.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        Size[] sizes = streamConfigs.getOutputSizes( ImageFormat.JPEG);
        Size smallerPreviewSize = chooseVideoSize( sizes);

        return smallerPreviewSize;
    }


  //Rerefences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997776/camera2-api-error-failed-to-create-capture-session
    protected Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
        List<Size> smallEnough = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Size size : choices) {
            if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 4 / 3 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
                smallEnough.add(size);
            }
        }
        if (smallEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.max(smallEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
        }

        return choices[choices.length - 1];
    }

    public CameraDevice getCamera() {
        return camera;
    }
}
```

**Helper to sort preview sizes:**

```
public class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }

}
```

I included the code for the regular camera only since the regular camera was not displaying, however the code for obtaining the ToF camera & listeners is the **exactly the same** except ToF specific logic.

I'm not seeing any exceptions or errors in the app logs, however the logs system show:

```
E/CHIUSECASE: [ERROR  ] chxusecase.cpp:967 ReturnFrameworkResult() ChiFrame: 0 App Frame: 0 - pResult contains more buffers (1) than the expected number of buffers (0) to return to the framework!
E/CamX: [ERROR][CORE   ] camxnode.cpp:4518 CSLFenceCallback() Node::FastAECRealtime_IFE0 : Type:65536 Fence 3 handler failed in node fence handler
E/CamX: [ERROR][SENSOR ] camxsensornode.cpp:9279 GetSensorMode() Sensor name: s5k2la
E/CamX: [ERROR][SENSOR ] camxsensornode.cpp:9302 GetSensorMode() W x H : 4032, 3024
E//vendor/bin/hw/vendor.samsung.hardware.camera.provider@3.0-service_64: vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:750: Error 0xe08132b8: remote_handle_invoke failed
E/CamX: [ERROR][ISP    ] camxispiqmodule.h:1871 IsTuningModeDataChanged() Invalid pointer to current tuning mode parameters (0x0)
E/CamX: [ERROR][PPROC  ] camxipenode.cpp:9529 GetFaceROI() Face ROI is not published
```

**1) How can I display the regular back facing camera as a Bitmap on TextureView, correctly?

2. Save that bitmap as JPEG or PNG in internal drive**

**Thanks a million!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to actually covert an Image in JPEG format to a Bitmap, you can't just copy the bytes over, as you do with:

```
                    Log.i(TAG,"AFTER width:"+width+",height:"+height);
                    //***here bitmap is black
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

                    buffer.rewind();
                    if (bitmap!=null) {
                        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
                    }
```

You need to actually decode the compressed JPEG, for example with [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeByteArray(kotlin.ByteArray,%20kotlin.Int,%20kotlin.Int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)).  That'll just produce a Bitmap from the Image contents, though you have to create a `byte[]` from the `plane[0]` ByteBuffer.

However, you really don't want to capture JPEGs here, those tend to be slow and won't get you very good frame rate.  Unless you have a strong reason, just use the TextureView's SurfaceTexture as a target for the camera (by creating a Surface from the SurfaceTexture).  That'll pass data in an efficient device-specific format, and you don't have to do any copying (still have to handle the scaling, though).

And if you need to modify the preview data before drawing, use the YUV_420_888 format, which is also efficient and will run at 30fps.  But that takes quite a bit more effort to draw to screen, since you'll have to convert to RGB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, but maybe I can push you in the right direction.

JPG is a compressed file format, so using it for a camera preview is a no-go. You generally want to let Camera directly draw onto the TextureView without any compression.

You did leave a comment that you need to do some kind of processing first, but did you try using a different file format if this kind of processing needs to be done realtime while showing a preview? Any kind of a compressed [image format](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat) will generally result in bad performance.

You can also show a preview directly while occasionally saving a compressed JPG/PNG on the external storage. You can do that with Camera2, though CameraX has a much simpler way of doing it via [use cases](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#structure).