# TextureView.getSurfaceTexture() returns null

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-camerax, textureview

I am trying to build a simple camera2 app to record videos and store on internal storage.

So on I have the following code:

```
package com.example.newcameraapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private static final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

    private CameraManager cameraManager;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private Size videoSize;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession;
    private String videoFilePath;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    private HandlerThread backgroundThread;
    private Handler backgroundHandler;

    private TextureView previewView;

    private static final int FIXED_FRAME_RATE = 30; // Fixed frame rate in frames per second

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        Button recordButton = findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
        recordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!isRecording) {
                    startRecording();
                } else {
                    stopRecording();
                }
            }
        });

        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void startCamera() {
        cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0]; // Use the first camera

            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            videoSize = chooseVideoSize(characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));

            cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
                    MainActivity.this.cameraDevice = cameraDevice;
                    startPreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
                    cameraDevice.close();
                    MainActivity.this.cameraDevice = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
                    cameraDevice.close();
                    MainActivity.this.cameraDevice = null;
                    // Handle camera error
                }
            }, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
        for (Size size : choices) {
            if (size.getWidth() == 1920 && size.getHeight() == 1080) {
                return size;
            }
        }
        return choices[choices.length - 1]; // Return the largest available size by default
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        try {
            closePreviewSession();
            SurfaceTexture texture = previewView.getSurfaceTexture();
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);

            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(previewSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    if (cameraDevice == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    cameraCaptureSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    // Handle configuration failure
                }
            }, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if (cameraDevice == null) {
            return;
        }

        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

        try {
            cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        if (cameraDevice == null || !previewView.isAvailable() || videoSize == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            closePreviewSession();
            setUpMediaRecorder();

            SurfaceTexture texture = previewView.getSurfaceTexture();
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);

            List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            surfaces.add(mediaRecorder.getSurface());

            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            for (Surface surface : surfaces) {
                captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            }

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    if (cameraDevice == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    cameraCaptureSession = session;
                    updatePreview();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mediaRecorder.start();
                            isRecording = true;
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    // Handle configuration failure
                }
            }, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000); // Adjust as needed
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(FIXED_FRAME_RATE); // Set the fixed frame rate
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private void closePreviewSession() {
        if (cameraCaptureSession != null) {
            cameraCaptureSession.close();
            cameraCaptureSession = null;
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (isRecording) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.reset();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            mediaRecorder = null;
            isRecording = false;
            startPreview();
        }
    }

    private String getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MyCameraApp");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        videoFilePath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4";
        return videoFilePath;
    }

    private boolean allPermissionsGranted() {
        for (String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recordButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Record"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After running the code (also checked all necessary permissions), following error occurs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.newcameraapp, PID: 6357
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(int, int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.newcameraapp.MainActivity.startPreview(MainActivity.java:136)
    at com.example.newcameraapp.MainActivity.access$400(MainActivity.java:41)
    at com.example.newcameraapp.MainActivity$2.onOpened(MainActivity.java:101)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:151)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Error is caused by `texture.setDefaultBufferSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());`

My layout xml seems correct and I called TextureView correctly too.

Can someone help?

Comment: Based on the original title, you're misreading the error. `previewView.getSurfaceTexture()` is returning null; not any attempt to find the View.  It's finding the TextureView successfully, so you need to instead figure out why `getSurfaceTexture()` is returning null (which I don't know the answer to, unfortunately, but hopefully that sets you in the right direction...).

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for clarification. You're right and actually Wang answer solved my problem of previewing the camera Image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `previewView.getSurfaceTexture()` into `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()` of `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener`.

For example, replacing the original `onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice)` with the following code can resolve it:

```
@Override
public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
    MainActivity.this.cameraDevice = cameraDevice;
    previewView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Wang, this actually solved the problem and now I can view the camera preview. Thanks for that! However, when I hit the "Record" button, screen freezes and following error is thrown `java.io.IOException: No valid output file Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:503: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided`

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about it, please check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997776/camera2-api-error-failed-to-create-capture-session) may help.

Comment: Hey Wang, thanks for response. I was actually able to overcome the issue by adjusting the number of encoded bits  on mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate() as sugessted by the answer you sent. Thanks again!